# GDI+ Image class problem

Tags: c++, gdi+

I am trying to read the image data from a PNG file using Image class in GDI+ and VC++ 2008. I have included gdiplus.h header file and also added Gdiplus.lib as a reference to the project. But when I compile the following code, I get the error that "Image" is an undeclared identifier. Could you please let me know how to read the data from the image using this class?

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "windows.h"
    #include "gdiplus.h"

    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
       Image *img;

       return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try "Gdiplus::Image".  All GDI+ classes are defined in the Gdiplus namespace.  You must either specify it as I suggest or add a "using namespace Gdiplus;"

Comment: thanks Goz, I added the namespace as you mentioned and the problem was solved. But when I run the program, the file is not being read. I am using the constructor to read from a bmp file. Can you tell me why this is happening?

Comment: The following is my code: Bitmap *img = Bitmap::FromFile(L"C:\\testbmp.bmp");

Comment: @Rakesh K: What is the value of img afterwards?  Is it a valid pointer or is it NULL?